# Python tcp server with multithreading can not print return value from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp

I am trying to set up a tcp server in Python using Multithreading. The problem is that the queue only return data from only one thread. That means it only prints the data from the thread created with 5555 or 5556. I confirmed both data reaches port by connecting one device per time but it does not print the result from connection to the other port when more than one device connected. 
Thanks for your help.

```
#!usr/bin/python
from threading import Thread
import socket
import sys
from queue import Queue
def clientthread(conn,q):
    buffer=""
    data = conn.recv(8192)
    buffer=data
    q.put(buffer)
    return buffer


def main():
    try:
        host = '169.254.162.144'
        port = 5555
        tot_socket =2
        list_sock = []
        conarr=[]
        threads=[]        
        for i in range(tot_socket):
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
            s.bind((host, port+i))
            s.listen(10)
            list_sock.append(s)
            print ("[*] Server listening on %s %d" %(host, (port+i)))
        for j in range(len(list_sock)):
            conn, addr = list_sock[j].accept()
            conarr.append(conn)
            print('[*] Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        while 1:
                queue1 = Queue()
                for j in range(len(list_sock)):
                    thread =Thread( target=clientthread, args=(conn, queue1) )
                    threads.append(thread)
                    thread.start()
                for thread in threads:
                    thread.join()
                while not queue1.empty():
                    result = queue1.get()
                    print(result)
                threads=[]         
        s.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt as msg:
        sys.exit(0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I guess you need to replace `conn` with `conarr[j]` in thread arguments

Comment: You saved the day:D